# How Chrome dev tools shows cookies

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-devtools

When I open the resources panel of Chrome's dev tools, I see a ton cookies set across many domains. I understand the definitional difference between a first party and third party cookie, but I'm still understanding what it means.

How does Chrome show 1st party cookies vs 3rd party cookies? When I visit Vice.com, for instance, I see many domains in the left hand column (www.vice.com, platform.tumblr.com, etc); if I select www.vice.com on the left hand column, I see many more domains (.google.com, .ads.pubmatic.com, .scorecardresearch.com, etc).

How should I interpret this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe @matt's comment more correctly answers it:

> I did a little more research and found this page:
>   developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Storage_Inspector It's about
>   mozilla developer tools but is still the same concept. Look at the
>   information near the top of the page. It seems that you are correct.
>   The listing on the left are iframes and everything listed to the right
>   are the cookies held inside that iframe. –  Matt 18 hours ago

Answer (score 4):

The Chrome DevTools [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/storage/cookies/) provides more information about this (quoted from a previous version of this page):

> Cookies are listed by domain. This includes the main document as well as all nested frames. Selecting one of these “frame groups” displays all cookies, for all resources, for all frames in that group. There are two consequences of this grouping to be aware of:
>
> - Cookies from different domains may appear in the same frame group.
> - The same cookie may appear in several frame groups.

Answer (score 1):

If I am interpreting this correctly, I believe the values on the right show  all of the cookies that are related to the domain you have selected on the left. In this case you have www.vice.com selected in blue. The other domains listed below this are the source domains of all the cookies found on vice.com (which is why you will see domain names to the right that are similar to the ones on the left).

If you click through the other domains in the left column, you will find all of the cookies that that particular domain has on vice.com.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Also, if you were to go to a .edu or a .gov website, you will not find nearly as many cookie domains listed in the left column, usually only a couple, maybe related to twitter or facebook. There are typically many more cookies associated with a .com website since these usually have ads, etc.

Comment: What does 'related' mean? Are the domains in the left column from iframes?

Comment: I did a little more research and found this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Storage_Inspector   It's about mozilla developer tools but is still the same concept. Look at the information near the top of the page. It seems that you are correct. The listing on the left are iframes and everything listed to the right are the cookies held inside that iframe.